# What does Rigel refer to in Device Model: PS3 Rigel?

Tags: ps3, netflix

In my Netflix settings, it lists the Device Model as PS3 Rigel. What is Rigel referring to?

Is this a name assigned by Sony or Netflix?

Does it refer to all PS3s? The generation of PS3? (Pretty sure mine's 3rd generation) Something even more granular (like specific model numbers)? Or is it actually referring to the PS3 firmware or the Netflix app version?

Comment: It sounds like the name you gave to your device at setup and probably forgot. In the Settings part of the XMB there's System Settings or something that'll let you check the device name.

Comment: A good guess, but I'm pretty sure that's not it. I doubled checked my PS3 isn't named Rigel (It's still the default PS3-XXX), and Netflix calls it Device Model, which does provide more information. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rigel" appears to be the codename of Netflix for PS3 version 2.0, according to [this slideshow](http://blog.streamingmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/2013SMEast-C101.pdf) purportedly by "David   Ronca", the "Manager, Encoding Tools" for Netflix.

The slideshow outlines the development history of the Netflix client. The info's a little dense without the accompanying slide notes, but I've taken a stab at assembling a timeline. In short:

- The first streaming client was an IE-only ActiveX plugin that hosted a Windows Media Player instance to which it delegated the actual playing of the video
- There was then an SDK (called CE1) on top of which a client for the Xbox was built, as well as the first Roku-based clients
- The ActiveX client was later replaced with a Silverlight client for better cross-platform capabilities
- This lead to a second version of the SDK for console boxes (CE2), which offered better capabilities and a Flash-based UI
- The first PS3 client, named "Vega", was based on the PS3's innate blue-ray reading technology
- The first Wii client was named "Link". It struggled with profile bloat introduced by DRM handling
- CE3 was released
- The first iOS client was called "Nato". It was built in a few weeks between Apple inviting them to be part of the iPad launch and the actual iPad launch. It uses HTTP Live Streaming, which was a totally new model for Netflix. It was based on Vega
- An upgrade to Vega rolled out this HTTP Live Streaming concept to the PS3
- Vega was replaced with Rigel, which is a native PS3 app (for better performance)
- Link was replaced with Kirby, which is again a native Wii app
- The latest SDK is CE3 version 2, which supports a standard called "DASH". As of May 2014, CE4 is under development.

I don't know if that helps, but I found it interesting at least :)

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you so much. Very informative, interesting, and I'm enjoying going through the slideshow now.

Answer (score 0):

Rigel is a microprocessor chipset

Comment: Please provide a source

Comment: Rigel WAS a microprocessor chipset. It seems it has been discontinued. It was not used in Playstation 3 and is not where the name came from. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigel_%28microprocessor%29